# ThinkingSphinx: Run SQL String Through Association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to get a geo search to work via an association.  Very similar to this fellow:

[How do I geo-search multiple models with ThinkingSphinx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266048/how-do-i-geo-search-multiple-models-with-thinkingsphinx)

The one difference is that I'm trying to combine the association syntax with custom SQL syntax.  It doesn't print any errors on indexing, but when I try to search it fails:

```
class Person
  define_index do
    indexes tags(:text), :as => :tags

    has media.location.lat('RADIANS(location.lat)'), :as => :lat, :type => :float
    has media.location.lng('RADIANS(location.lng)'), :as => :lng, :type => :float
  end

  sphinx_scope(:by_location) { |loc|
    { :geo => [loc.lat.to_radians, loc.lng.to_radians],
      :with => {"@geodist" => 0.0..loc.radius },
      :latitude_attr => "lat",
      :longitude_attr => "lng"
    }
  }
end

#running this search from console
Person.by_location(Location.first)
```

This is the error:

> ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index fulfillment_core: unknown latitude attribute 'lat'

I've tried configuring it without the SQL string - this runs without error, but the math is of course totally wrong as it's trying to do radian operations on degrees.

Is there any way to combine the conversion and the association, or am I stuck storing my data as radians instead of degrees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your index definition isn't quite right. Try the following:

```
define_index do
  indexes tags(:text), :as => :tags

  # forces the join on media and location associations
  join media.location

  has 'RADIANS(location.lat)', :as => :lat, :type => :float
  has 'RADIANS(location.lng)', :as => :lng, :type => :float
end
```

Comment: Perfect!  The join was what I was missing.  Thanks Pat!

Comment: Thanks, Pat! Your answers are much appreciated (I keep seeing them all the time)!

Comment: Is there a way to name the "join tables" up there? For instance, let's assume the Person above has a location as well as media.location. How can you distinguish between the two in the has expression?

Comment: Alright cool.. Found the answer. If we join on location then join on media.location, we can do RADIANS(location.lat) and this will reference the person's location, and RADIANS(media_locations.lat) and this will reference the media locations. In case we can't find the name of the table, look inside the generated development.sphinx.conf file, take the sql_query_range query and check the name of the tables toward the end of the expression =)